# Wget - how not to download next files if there is no connection

Tags: recursion, timeout, wget

When using wget with the recursive option (-r), if the page.html contains 100 different download links to 100 different files, if the connection between the PC and the device is interrupted (after the download of 20 file), the program continues trying to download the other 80 files, so wasting a lot of time.
I tried theese options but nothing...
`-T 1`
`-t 1`
`--dns-timeout=1`
`--connect-timeout=1`
`--read-timeout=1`
Is there way to stop wget after N minutes of no connection?

Comment: Just an idea: create a script which launches wget and keeps track of its PID, then loop while wget is active doing a sleep, then a ping to detect if connection is alive. If not, kill wget.

Comment: yes, it seems to be a good solution, but is it possible that I can't do something similar directly from wget?